# yii2 bootstrap4 выдает ошибку

Tags: yii2, nginx, composer

установил через composer bootstrap4

> composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4

добавил

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

Но в логах вот такая ошибка

```
2019/05/28 13:19:09 [error] 911#911: *54 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/var/www/server/src/web/../environment): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/server/src/web/index.php on line 4" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
2019/05/28 13:19:09 [error] 911#911: *54 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\InvalidConfigException: A circular dependency is detected for bundle 'app\assets\AppAsset'. in /var/www/server/src/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php:295
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/server/src/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetBundle.php(125): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('app\\assets\\AppA...')
#1 /var/www/server/src/views/layouts/main.php(6): yii\web\AssetBundle::register(Object(yii\web\View))
#2 /var/www/server/src/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(348): require('/var/www/server...')
#3 /var/www/server/src/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(257): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('/var/www/server...', Array)
#4 /var/www/server/src/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(399): yii\base\View->renderFile('/var/www/server...', Array, Object(app\controllers\SiteController))
#5 /var/www/server/src/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(385): yii\base\Controller->renderContent('')
#6 /var/www/server/src/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorAction.php(139): y" while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема произошла из-за прав в linux. После настройки прав, все запустилось